# bounding box in fcose layout doesn't work

Tags: cytoscape.js, bounding-box

Is bounding box with fcose layout supported? If not, then are there any workarounds?

I would like to separate one group of nodes in the top half with the rest in the bottom half.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, both fcose and cose-bilkent layout algorithms don't currently support bounding box. Maybe, you can apply the layout on subgraphs and then move one subgraph to top and the other subgraph to bottom as a workaround.